# Oauth2 refresh_token confusion

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token

Im using a 3rd party api server side, which generates an `access_token` and a `refresh_token` as per normal via a `grant_type=password` request. I'm confused because this api does not appear to support `grant_type=refresh_token` - I keep getting the unsupported grant type error. Does it even matter, when you can just handle unauthorized errors by re-firing the password grant request? is this typical for 3rd party api use?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the [resource owner password credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) issues a refresh token, is so that the client does not have to keep the password around in clear text for later use.

The client is supposed to collect username and password, use it to get an access and refresh token and discard the password.

Make sure to send a `POST` request with Content-Type set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and include client credentials in a basic authorization header if your authorization server requires it. See [RFC-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6) for an example.